# PySpark: Timeslice and split rows in dataframe with 5 minutes interval on a specific condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
+-----+----------+--------------------------+-----------+
|id   | sourceid |        timestamp         | indicator |
+-----+----------+--------------------------+-----------+
| 0   |  128     |  2019-12-03 12:00:00.0   | 0         |
| 1   |  128     |  2019-12-03 12:30:00.0   | 1         |
| 2   |  128     |  2019-12-03 12:37:00.0   | 0         |
| 3   |  128     |  2019-12-03 13:15:00.0   | 1         |
| 4   |  128     |  2019-12-03 13:17:00.0   | 0         | 
+-----+----------+--------------------------+-----------+
```

I am trying to split the `timestamp` column into rows of 5 minute time intervals for `indicator` values which are not **0**.

***Explanation:***

- The first entry is at time `timestamp = 2019-12-03 12:00:00.0, indicator= 0`, do nothing.
- Moving on to the next entry with `timestamp = 2019-12-03 12:30:00.0, indicator= 1`, I want to split `timestamp` into rows with a **5** minutes interval till we reach the next entry which is `timestamp = 2019-12-03 12:37:00.0, indicator= 0`.
- If there is a case where `timestamp = 2019-12-03 13:15:00.0, indicator = 1` and the next `timestamp = 2019-12-03 13:17:00.0, indicator = 0`, I'd like to split the row considering both the times have indicator as **1** as 13:17:00.0 falls between 13:15:00.0 - 13:20:00.0 as shown below.

How can I achieve this with PySpark?

**Expected Output:**

```
+-----+----------+--------------------------+-------------+
|id   | sourceid |        timestamp         | indicator   |
+-----+----------+--------------------------+-------------+
| 1   | 128      |  2019-12-03 12:30:00.0   | 1           |
| 1   | 128      |  2019-12-03 12:35:00.0   | 1           |
| 4   | 128      |  2019-12-03 13:15:00.0   | 1           |
| 4   | 128      |  2019-12-03 13:20:00.0   | 1           |
+-----+----------+--------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: your question is not very clear, what if there is an entry at time: `timestamp = 2019-12-03 12:33:00.0, indicator= 0`, also why the last row id=3 is discarded? please add more sample rows to describe and clarify all potential cases.

Comment: @jxc I have updated my question with the case you've mentioned.

Comment: what if there are two consecutive `1` in 5 minutes? if a `1` is not followed by an `0`, it should be discarded??

Comment: @jxc yes it should be discarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can filter rows based on indicators on the current and the next rows, and then use `array` + `explode` to create new rows (for testing purpose, I added some more rows into your original example):

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

w1 = Window.partitionBy('sourceid').orderBy('timestamp')

# add a flag to check if the next indicator is '0'       
df1 = df.withColumn('next_indicator_is_0', F.lead('indicator').over(w1) == 0) 
df1.show(truncate=False)
+---+--------+---------------------+---------+-------------------+
|id |sourceid|timestamp            |indicator|next_indicator_is_0|
+---+--------+---------------------+---------+-------------------+
|0  |128     |2019-12-03 12:00:00.0|0        |false              |
|1  |128     |2019-12-03 12:30:00.0|1        |true               |
|2  |128     |2019-12-03 12:37:00.0|0        |false              |
|3  |128     |2019-12-03 13:12:00.0|1        |false              |
|4  |128     |2019-12-03 13:15:00.0|1        |true               |
|5  |128     |2019-12-03 13:17:00.0|0        |false              |
|6  |128     |2019-12-03 13:20:00.0|1        |null               |
+---+--------+---------------------+---------+-------------------+

df1.filter("indicator = 1 AND next_indicator_is_0") \
   .withColumn('timestamp', F.expr("explode(array(`timestamp`, `timestamp` + interval 5 minutes))")) \
   .drop('next_indicator_is_0') \
   .show(truncate=False)
+---+--------+---------------------+---------+
|id |sourceid|timestamp            |indicator|
+---+--------+---------------------+---------+
|1  |128     |2019-12-03 12:30:00.0|1        |
|1  |128     |2019-12-03 12:35:00  |1        |
|4  |128     |2019-12-03 13:15:00.0|1        |
|4  |128     |2019-12-03 13:20:00  |1        |
+---+--------+---------------------+---------+
```

**Note:** you can reset `id` column by using `F.row_number().over(w1)` or `F.monotonically_increasing_id()` based on your requirements.

Comment: Array explode to add new row...never thought it this way.. nice approach